# #10 envelope page size -- Skim / Adobe default to 8.5" x 11"

Tags: pdftex, pdf, mac

Each time I print an envelope, I've been manually selecting the #10 envelope size from the Skim print menu on an OSX machine because the application thinks it is 8.5" x 11".  Is there any configuration in the LaTeX code that would create a *.pdf that Skim could automatically recognize as a # 10 envelope?  Adobe Acrobat Professional has the same issue.

```
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage[left=.2in,top=0.15in,papersize={4.12in,9.50in},landscape,twoside=false]{geometry}
\setlength\parskip{0pt}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\large{
\textbf{Sender Name}

\textbf{Company Name}

\textbf{Street Address}

\textbf{City, State \ Zip}
}

\vspace{1.0in}\LARGE
\setlength\parindent{3.5in}

Recipient Name

Company Name

Street Address

City, State \ Zip

\end{document}
```

Comment: When you view the document properties in Adobe (Reader), does the page size say `9.50 x 4.12 in`?

Comment: Adobe Acrobat Professional -- print popup screen:  Document:  9.5 x 4.1in; Paper:  11.0 x 8.5in.  Skim defaults to paper size US Letter 8.5 by 11.00 inches.  Regular letters and legal documents (letter size) and also # 10 envelopes are the two kinds of documents that I frequently print.

Comment: When I select # 10 envelope from the Skim print menu, both of my HP laserjet printers access the envelope tray number 2 and print the envelope.  I remember configuring the paper tray number 2 in each printer a couple of years ago, but I cannot remember exactly what I did to each printer -- something in the menu settings of each printer.  I think the solution I am looking for might be possible, because I can print an envelope from Microsoft Word Mac and the printer automatically selects the correct tray.  In MS Word Mac, the page setup option has an option for # 10 envelope.

Comment: The problem here might be in the communication setup to the printer, and not so much LaTeX. In fact, LaTeX seems to be doing everything correct in creating the appropriate document size.

Comment: Ah . . . I was hoping to embed something in the *.pdf through LaTeX that said:  "Hello printer -- this is a #10 Envelope, so access the correct tray."

Comment: I've spent an hour reading various threads and articles on Google, and it appears as though OSX has this built-in limitation.  It is necessary to manually select the paper size (if different than the default defined in System Preferences / Print & Scan options), or use an Automator type script, or set up Adobe Reader in a virtual Windows container -- e.g., Parallels.  The Adobe for Windows does have an option "Choose Paper Source By PDF Page Size"; but OSX has no such option.  :(

Comment: Argh - don't use `letter`. It's ancient and there are better alternatives: e.g. `scrlttr2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adobe Reader 11.0.03 for OSX (Mountain Lion) now has an option "Choose Paper Source by PDF page size".  Then it is just a matter of manually configuring each printer to know what tray to use for appropriate paper size.

Adobe Acrobat Pro OSX Version 9 does not have the option to "Choose Paper Source by PDF page size".

I do not believe the current version of Skim or Preview for OSX have this option either.